# Split an Array From GUI

Tags: java, arrays

How to split an array? This is an addStudent method that takes in an array of courses that have taken, taking, to be taken, from GUI.

```
public void addStudent(String firstName, String lastName, String phone, String address, double gpa, String major, String[] haveTaken, String[] taking, String[]toBeTaken, int crdit){
        String[] taken = haveTaken.split(","); //this part screams at me
        Person temp = 
           new Student(firstName, lastName, phone, address, gpa, major, haveTaken, taking, toBeTaken, credit);
        p.add(temp);
    }
```

Comment: `split` is a method of `String` not `String[]`

Comment: What does ``haveTaken`` look like and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want to split the array?

Comment: I am using GUI to input the data. After receiving the data from haveTaken.getText(), the Array String of courses will have to be split. Such as [CST141, CST161, CST323].

Comment: "How to split an array"? array is already split .maybe you want to spilt elemtents of array

Comment: So you want an array, but you already have an array. What's the problem then? Please try to ask a clear question.

Comment: You will need to iterate through the string array named taken to get the desired data. Use a 'for loop'.

Answer (score 1):

OR....perhaps what you're looking for is something like this:

```
String[] taken = Arrays.toString(hasTaken).replace("[","").replace("]","").split(", ");
```

The space after the comma within the split() argument is not a typo. Arrays.toString() method places a space after each delimter.

**EDIT:**

Okay James, I just noticed your comment:

> I am using GUI to input the data. After receiving the data from
>   **haveTaken.getText()**, the Array String of courses will have to be
>   split. Such as [CST141, CST161, CST323].

Here is the confusion, you declare an argument for the the **addStudent()** method named **haveTaken** as a String Array but in your comment you are telling use that you getting the data from a GUI component that supports the **.getText()** method like perhaps a JTextField. But then again you are showing us a string of data which is actually the returned output of the **Arrays.toString()** method ( [CST141, CST161, CST323] ).

**Which is it???**

Is the **haveTaken** variable actually a String Array variable or is it the variable name for one of your GUI components?

If **haveTaken** is in fact a String Array variable then the code I posted above will work for you however there are more definite methods for copying one Array contents into another Array like using a '**for loop**', **.clone()**, **System.arraycopy()**, or **Arrays.copyOf()**.

If however the **haveTaken** variable represents the variable name of a GUI component and you are calling the delimited text supplied within that component an Array then...Stop doing that and Stop 
representing the text from that component as a String Array argument for your **addStudent()** method. 
It should be:  ....,String haveTaken, ....  **Not**  ...., String[] haveTaken, .... The answer now also changes because there are formatting precautions you may need to take before carrying out the Split. What if one or more comma delimiters were not supplied? Spaces (perhaps several) placed before or after each comma delimiter? This formatting should be done at the data entry level so as to ensure a consistent format for processing.

I highly doubt that you are expecting Users to supply data within a text field component in the fashion of:  **[CST141, CST161, CST323]**. If you are then...Stop that too since it's prone to entry errors. But if the data supplied within the text field component is in this fashion:  CST141,CST161,CST323 then your initial attempt to Split should have worked.

Here is the big question I'm sure we all want to know: **"Why do you want to Split a String Array?"** Knowing this will definitely give you satisfactory results.

Comment: This probably works but so does doing nothing. Why would you want to split an array you just joined?

Comment: It definitly seems seems odd @Aaron considering the 'for loop', .clone(), System.arraycopy(), or Arrays.copyOf() would all suffice for Copying an Array which is essensially all this is doing in this particular case. I suppose it sort of goes hand in hand with: "why would you pick your nose after you blew it?". Ironically enough though, placing the array to copy into a single string and then splitting it opens up all the capabilities of split() for whatever reason. Maybe to get rid of a booger caught the initial Array ( .split(", CST323") ).